# Any idea why this DateTime.Parse generates an error?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I do not know what I'm over looking...  Why does this generate an exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."?

```
string dt = "7/28/‎2018 ‏‎2:48:32 PM";
try
{
  DateTime Test = DateTime.Parse(dt);
}
catch { }
```

I stepped through my code several times before I commented it out and replaced with the above as a test.  the value I am assigning to dt is actually what gets assigned in my program.  I was originally using something like:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(dt, out DateTime Timestamp))
{ ... }
```

Not that it matters, but I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and .Net 4.6.2.

Comment: That means this is _not_ a standart date and time format for your `CurrentCulture` settings. Try `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` methods instead using with `M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt` format and _proper_ culture like `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: See below comments.  My current culture is set correctly.  I wanted to use current culture and the dates and times will be in the current culture format.  I just finished re-installing Visual Studio and now it is compiling correctly and generating the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was something in Visual Studio 2017.  Re-installed and now the original code works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.Parse()` will try to guess the format of the given date. If you are sure the dates will always be in a particular format use `ParseExact()`:

```
string dt = "7/28/‎2018 ‏‎2:48:32 PM";
try
{
    DateTime Test = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Note that h(can also use hh) is used instead of HH because it's a 12 hour format and HH represents 24 hour format

Comment: I had not considerend ParseExact() because I do not know what format I will get time in (may or may not have seconds and or am/pm).  That said, ParseExact still did not work.  And because it did not, I tried on another machine and the original code worked.  THERE IS SOMETHING WRONG ON MY MACHINE.  +1 because it made me think to try it on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse` is culture-sensitive. By default, it uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to get the proper datetime format. If you need to parse the string using a different culture, you need to use the Parse overload that takes an `IFormatProvider` argument.

Example, in an invariant culture (useful for persistence):

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("07/31/2017 16:15:26", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.Write(dt.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 07/31/2017 16:15:26
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  I actually want to use the current culture.  In the case where it will be run in Warsaw, Tel Aviv, Shanghai, I need to use the local culture and the input will be in the local culture format.

It is working now.  I compiled from a different machine without changing the code.  Something is wrong with my machine.  I'm removing Visual Studio and re-installing (yes, I tried restarting).